# Incrementally build and use a map during compile time

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, compile-time, compile-time-type-checking

I would like to build a map of used types during compile time and verify that all entries are consistent.

An example usage would be a set of configuration settings that are are defined from their usage in the code.

```
template <typename T>
constexpr void add_to_map(std::string key, T) {
  // Check that key isn't saved in the map with a different type. Compilation error if check fails.
  // Add new entry to map
}

// Exampel usage
template <typename T>
void set_setting(std::string key, T value) {
  add_to_map(key, value); // Check that this key/type combination is unique

  // Add/set the value of key in some container, e.g. std::map
}

template <typename T>
T get_setting(std::string key) {
  add_to_map(key, T{}); // Check that this key/type combination is unique

 // Return the value for key
}

int main() {
  set_setting("pi", 3.14);  // OK
  set_setting("answer", 42); // OK
  get_setting<int>("answer"); // OK
  set_setting("pi", 3.0);  // OK

  set_setting("answer", 42.0); // Error, wrong type
  get_setting<bool>("pi"); // Error wrong type
}
```

The question is how to implement add_to_map(). Note that this is not building the map of settings. It's building a map of the settings types. This map is only used during compile time.

Keys would obviously have to be hard coded.

I assume this this is something that can't be done. But I would be happy to see a partial solution. C++17 would be best, but usage of C++20 or even standard proposals would also be of interest.

Comment: Have you checked what [Boost.Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/) offers? There's **_a lot_** of compile-time utilities in that library.

Comment: Let's remove the word 'map' from the picture for a moment. You want something that lets you specify pairs of arguments and verify during compilation whether a pair a) is unique, b) exists somewhere? Why not plain template specialization?

Comment: Even though it could be useful to access the whole set of pairs, restating the problem to handle individual pairs would solve the the problem as stated. But how do you do this with template specialization and have strings as keys?